# DataSnap Callbacks with Authentication

Tags: delphi, authentication, callback, delphi-xe, datasnap

I can use "Callbacks" between datasnap server and clients given as an example [here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41374) by Pawel Glowacki.
But when I add DSAuthenticationManager1 on the server form with simple authentication then at the client sides I can not registered callbacks.

I get this error: "Exception class TDBXError with message 'Remote error: Authentication manager rejected user credentials. This may due to invalid combination of DS user name and password'."

I added login details to SQLConnection at the client like this:

```
SQLConnection1.Params.Values['DSAuthenticationUser'] :=  Username;
SQLConnection1.Params.Values['DSAuthenticationPassword'] := Password;
```

So my SQLConnection1 successfully connects to server. But I can not find any way for DSAuthenticationManager1.

How can I import login params to DSAuthenticationManager1?

Comment: What does your server-side `DSAuthenticationManager1.OnUserAuthenticate` do?  It has a `var Valid: Boolean` parameter.  Are you setting that to `True` on the server-side?  If not, you will get the error message you indicated.

Comment: For example: 
`valid := (user='admin') and (password='123');`

Comment: Have you debugged the datasnap server during the authentication to verify that the assigned username and password values are being properly sent and evaluated in the `OnUserAuthenticate()` event?

Comment: @James; yes, when I debug, DSClientCallbackChannelManager sent empty username and password. So If I apply login conditions DSClientCallbackChannelManager raise exeption.

Comment: If the username and password are empty on the server side, then there is likely something on the client side isn't setup correctly.  Why don't you edit your question and include the actual code that you use to connect to the DataSnap server?  What are the properties of the `SQLConnection1` component?  What code is executed to connect to the server?  Etc.

Comment: There is no problem with SQLConnection1. The problem is DSClientCallbackChannelManager. In Delphi XE DSClientCallbackChannelManager has NOT DSAuthUser and DSAuthPassword property. So SQLConnection1 connects to server succesfully but DSClientCallbackChannelManager doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TDSClientCallbackChannelManager` component in Delphi-XE does not include the same properties as in Delphi-XE2.  When I add this component to my project (XE2), I have `Username` and `Password` properties, which are passed to the DataSnap server's `DSAuthenticationManager.OnUserAuthenticate` method whenever `RegisterCallback()` or `UnregisterCallback()` are called.

Do you have the latest XE update?  If username and password aren't in the latest update, then you will likely need to upgrade to XE2 in order to use `TDSAuthenticationManager` in the DataSnap server and `TDSClientCallbackChannelManager` in the client.

I thought that perhaps you could create your own class from `TSDClientCallbackChannelManager` and override the methods that add the username and password to the DBXConnection -- thus giving you a way to add them yourself.  I tried this, but the methods that need to be overridden are not `virtual`.  I thought perhaps I could hide the ancestor methods by promoting methods with the same names in my new class as `public`, whereas they were `protected` in the ancestor class.  It generated code and linked it into my client app (evident by the blue dots next to the new lines of code), but it wouldn't call my code at run-time.  It always called the ancestor methods instead (`DBXConnectionProperties` and `ExecuteRemote`).

I think your only solution is to either update to XE2, or not use the authentication manager on the server.